# How Can I find the most visible child element of a div via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Greetings from the not so dark side of web development!

I'm putting together my portfolio of web development. It consists of a series of images, kind of formatted like a slide show. When I scroll, it snaps to the next slide in line. The system worked well.

Now I've added a drag-to-scroll mechanic, that works, just not completely with the other plugin I made for it.

That's where I need your help. I need to find a way to use jQuery and Javascript that will calculate the most visible child element of a div `.body-container`. I need to find which div has the most rendered pixels on screen. With this, I can find out which slide to snap it to and can finally fix the bugs that plague the two pieces of code together.

---

**The Code**

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="body-container" style="top:40px">
        <div class="section one">

        </div>
        <div class="section two">

        </div>
        <div class="section three">

        </div>
        <div class="section four">

        </div>
        <div class="section five">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-left: 40px solid white;
  border-right: 40px solid white;  
}

body:before, body:after {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

body:before {
    top: 0;
}

body:after {
    bottom: 0;
}

.body-container {
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  overflow: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  height: 500vh;

  -webkit-transition: top 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: top 300ms ease;
  -ms-transition: top 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: top 300ms ease;
  transition: top 300ms ease;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  background: url(../img/one.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.two {
  background: url(../img/two.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.three {
  background: url(../img/three.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.four {
  background: url(../img/four.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.five {
  background: url(../img/five.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

JS:

```
$.fn.isVisible = function() {
            var rect = this[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            return (
                (rect.height > 0 || rect.width > 0) &&
                    rect.bottom >= 0 &&
                    rect.right >= 0 &&
                    rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
                    rect.left <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
            );
        };

        $(function() {

            var slide = 1;
            var scrlHeight;

            $(window).on('wheel', function(e) {
                var delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY;
                if (delta > 0) {
                    if (slide != 5) {
                        slide = slide + 1;
                        scrlHeight = slide * -100 + 100 + "vh";
                        $('.body-container').css('top', 'calc(' + scrlHeight + ' + 40px)');
                    }
                } else {
                    if (slide != 1) {
                        slide = slide - 1;
                        scrlHeight = slide * -100 + 100 + "vh";
                        $('.body-container').css('top', 'calc(' + scrlHeight + ' + 40px)');
                    }
                }
            });

            var mState = 0;
            var posX = 0;
            var posY = 0;

            $(window).mousemove(function(m){
                if(mState === 1){
                    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + (posY - m.pageY)); 
                    $(window).scrollLeft($(window).scrollLeft() + (posX - m.pageX));
                }
            });

            $(window).mousedown(function(m){
                mState = 1;
                posY = m.pageY;
                posX = m.pageX;
            });

            $(window).mouseup(function(){
                mState = 0;
                $('body').html($('.body-container').mostVisible);
            });

        });
```

A live Demo can be found at the following URL:

https://andrewrobinson-cheapskate01.c9users.io/index.html

Comment: Is this task just finding the width times the height (`ele.width()*ele.height()`) of each element in `.body-container` using a for loop and identifying which has the greatest product?

Comment: No, all of the elements are the same, what I am trying to figure is at any given moment after the user scrolls, which element takes up more of the screen.